# Dismiss notifications from the Android O long-press menu, will not remove the summary parent of the bundled notifications from the drawer

Tags: android, notifications, android-8.0-oreo

We're using inline reply & bundled notifications in our app (for instant messages).

On Android O, users can dismiss notifications from the shortcut popup, and from the drawer as well, but we found that, when all the notifications are dismissed, the summary notification of the bundle will be left there not removed.

This happens only when the last notification is dismissed from the shortcut popup, if it's dismissed from the drawer, everything is ok.

- notifications in the shortcut popup

[image: shortcut popup]

- bundled notifications in the drawer

[image: bundled notifications in the drawer]

- the bundle summary is not removed, when all notifications are dismissed

[image: the group summary is not removed]

- I'm using the emulator with system image level 26

[image: system image]

I'm not sure if the future release of Android O will handle such a scenario, if not, how can I solve it? Is there anyone encounter the similar problem as well?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that notifications can be auto-bundled on 24+ devices. So the manually created summary notification is no longer needed. 
Please refer to [The Example Project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearNotifications/blob/fd7cdc51a76e6beb7d7b428a8c30ab745e3bbfb8/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/wearable/wear/wearnotifications/MainActivity.java#L310)